# iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable contains unsupported architeture(s): armv7s

Tags: architecture, frameworks, executable, armv7

i'im seeing a problem releasing on AppStore my App! 
The validation process say: "iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable contains unsupported architeture(s): armv7s"

this is my library linked: 
CoreLocation (required)
Twitter (optional)
QuartzCore (required)
MapKit (required)
UIKit (required)
Foundation (required)
CoreGraphics (required)
libGoogleAnalytics.a (required)
libsqlite3.dylib (required)
CFNetwork (required)

I've also tryed to remove GoogleAnalytics Library but the problem is the same! Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I submitted an app 2 days ago and it passed validation.  So it looks like a change that was introduced since 10/29/12.

Answer (score 6):

Based on discussions at the Apple dev forums (https://devforums.apple.com/message/749949) it looks like this is a bug affecting a lot of people.  Probably due to a change in Apple's validations servers.

I was able to work around it by changing the build architecture in Build Settings from Standard(armv7,armv7s) to armv7 and rebuilding.  This should only have the effect that the compiled code is not optimized for iPhone 5.  It will still run, but may not be quite as fast as if it were compiled for armv7s.  I suspect the performance difference would be negligible in most cases.

Comment: People in the forum thread you link to have suggested that it works when you build the app with Xcode 4.5.1 and submit it with Xcode 4.5.2 GM seed.

You can also download Application Loader 2.8 from iTunes Connect > Manage Your Applications > Download Application Loader and use that to submit your app.

Answer (score 2):

This helped me:

> Project -> Build Settings -> remove the architecture from "valid
>   architectures" as well as setting the "Build Active Architecture Only"
>   to Yes in the Project

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today. My app has no third-party libraries.

12 days ago I submitted a build from Xcode 4.5.1 that was subsequently reviewed and released to the App Store. Today I tried to submit a new build and suddenly received this error.

I then tried to validate the same executable (not a rebuild) from within Xcode that I had submitted 12 days ago and that had passed validation and is now available for download in the App Store, but this time it failed validation with the above error.

Performing step 4 above allowed me to submit the new build. But the executable is smaller even though I have added a small amount of code and three small png/jpegs. This makes me think that armv7s code is missing from the archive.

What is happening? Why should step 4 above 'work'? Why does an executable that previously submitted OK and was released suddenly no longer pass validation?

Note: this is not a duplicate of any previous post that I was able to find 15 hours ago. This is the first time I have seen any mention made of seeing this error when submitting to iTunes Connect rather than receiving a compiler warning. So please do not mark this as a duplicate. It is not.

Comment: What step 4 are you referring to?

Comment: 'Set "Build Active Architecture Only" to Yes' listed in the post from beev.

Comment: I had this exact same problem today. I tried going back and building a version that I submitted sucessfully (and has already passed review) only a few days ago, and now it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here are ones that I did not find ideal, mainly because they essentially suggest that you remove armv7s support from your app. While that will make you app pass validation, that could potentially make your app run slower on the iPhone 5.

Here is the workaround I'm using (though, I must say that I wouldn't call this a solution).

Instead of using XCode Organizer, I'm uploading the binary using Application Loader.

To upload the binary using Application Loader

Open Organizer > Right Click on Archive > Reveal in Finder.

Right Click the Archive file > Show Archive Content

Go to Products > Application > YourAPP.app

Compress YourAPP.app and upload using Application Loader.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the fact I was using an old version of Application Loader.

The solution for me was to download the latest version of Application Loader iTunes Connect > Manage Your Applications > Download Application Loader and try again.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

1.Select your project in Xcode (with the blue icon)

2.Select Build Settings

3.Set the view to All/Combined

4.Set "Build Active Architecture Only" to Yes